# Django Rest Framework: Access context from nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If I have a parent serializer, how can I pass the context / request to the child serializer? My nested serializer needs the request context from the parent in order to generate absolute URLs.

```
class Post(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
    files = FileSerializer(many=True)
```

Comment: You don't need to pass context to nested serializer, it's done by default.

Comment: @dikamilo you should write that as an answer ;)